# How to append a column of values from each file in directory using another specific column as an index in Python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, data-wrangling

I have 10 tab-delimited files with this overall structure:

| tracking_id | gene_id | gene_short_name | FPKM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ENSG00000121410.11 | ENSG00000121410.11 | A1BG | 30.8275 |

Each file has the exact same number of rows and columns, but they are not sorted the same (i.e. the gene_short_name column is sorted differently for each file). I'm trying to write a python script to iterate through each file (sample), collect the gene_short_name and FPKM for each individual sample, and append this to a new dataframe, with the gene_short_name acting as the index and the individual FPKM values making up the columns of the dataframe. I wrote this so far:

```
for file in glob.glob('/Cufflinks_Output/*.cufflinks.genes.fpkm_tracking'):
    # read data
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter = "\t")
    # drop duplicates
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=['gene_short_name'], keep='first')
    # sort by gene_short_name
    df.sort_values(by=df['gene_short_name'], ascending=True, axis=1, inplace=True)
    # add list of gene_short_name to array which will be appended later
    collected_columns  = [df['gene_short_name'],]
    # extract name
    id_ = file.split('/')[-1].split('.cufflinks.genes.fpkm_tracking')[0]
    # rename column to include sampleID
    df.rename({'FPKM': f'{id_}_FPKM'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

    collected_columns.append(df[f'{id_}_FPKM'])

final_df = pd.concat(collected_columns, join='inner', axis=1)
final_df.head()
```

I'm getting a key error on the sorting step now, so I tried this instead:

```
for file in glob.glob('/Cufflinks_Output/*.cufflinks.genes.fpkm_tracking'):
    # read data
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter = "\t")
    # drop duplicates
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=['gene_short_name'], keep='first')
    # sort by gene_short_name
    #df.sort_values(by=df['gene_short_name'], ascending=True, axis=1, inplace=True)
    # add list of gene_short_name to array which will be appended later
    collected_columns  = [df['gene_short_name'],]
    # extract name
    id_ = file.split('/')[-1].split('.cufflinks.genes.fpkm_tracking')[0]
    # rename column to include sampleID
    df.rename({'FPKM': f'{id_}_FPKM'}, axis=1, inplace=True)

    collected_columns.append(df[f'{id_}_FPKM'])

final_df = pd.concat(collected_columns, join='inner', axis=1)
final_df.head()
```

|  | gene_short_name | sr_HR11_FPKM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | OR4G4P | 0.0 |
| 1 | FAM138A | 0.0 |
| 2 | AL627309.6 | 0.0 |
| 3 | AL627309.7 | 0.0 |
| 4 | AL627309.2 | 0.0 |

*Edit: Yes, the 0's for the `sr_HR11_FPKM` column are correctly associated with the appropriate gene symbol*

I have 10 files and for some reason, it only seemed to compile `sr_HR11` which isn't even the first file in the directory. I've been stuck for awhile, hoping anyone can perhaps take a look and give some suggestions? I really want to ensure the columns appended are matching with their appropriate gene_short_name, as those columns are not sorted in any particular way and each file seems to have them in a scrambled order. Thank you SO much!!

Answer (score 1):

When doing this Pandas does not allow for two "Identical keys" if that is what could be causing this in the gene_short_name column (when you attempt to combine the two).

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
    for f in glob.glob('/Cufflinks_Output/*.cufflinks.genes.fpkm_tracking'):
         df1 = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter = "\t")         
         df = pd.concat([df, df1]) 
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['gene_short_name'], keep='first')
df = df.sort_values(by=['gene_short_name'], ascending=True, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Then try the rest of your code :)

EDIT: Make sure you are re-assigning df to each change that you make ie: `df = df.drop_duplicates()` not just `df.drop_duplicates()`

in order to get your columns in the correct order, make a list (in my example I called it "cols") with your header names in the correct order and use `df = df[cols]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response! I tried this and kept getting a "Key Error" which is too long to paste in this text box... maybe it would make most sense to first merge the other columns, based on the gene_short_name? I'm unsure about how to do this without sorting though, especially since I need to iterate through for all the files in my directory. Then, I would only need to remove duplicates at that point. Let me know what you think!

Comment: try inserting 'df1 = df1.reset_index()' after reading the file 'df1 = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter = "\t")'.  again, would not recommend making gene_short_name a primary key as it is repeated more than once. can you provide me more info about the "Key Error"? on which line does it not crash?